# Yii and Mod Rewrite: redirect to user language translated url

Tags: .htaccess, yii, multilingual

I'm developing a multilanguage web app with Yii.

I applied changes to hide the index.php, changed urlFormat to path and added to the url path a slug with the user language example /it/index.php /en/index.php etc...

The problem now is that I need to redirect automatically to a different url once the user chooses another language. For example:

http://localhost/~antonio/project/it/women
needs to redirect to:
http://localhost/~antonio/project/it/femme

I have been playing with htaccess with no luck at all. Here is the actual code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~antonio/project/
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

#My redirection code (tried a good few more to no use apart from this)

```
RewriteRule ^it/women$ it/femme
```

I would really appreciate any help on this issue, as it is driving me mad.

Thanks

Edit::

I surrendered with mod_rewrite. I found another solution by adding this code to /layout/main.php:

```
<?php 
$onurl = Yii::app()->getRequest()->requestUri;
if ($onurl == "/~antonio/project/it/women") {
    $this->redirect("/~antonio/project/it/femme");
} elseif ($onurl == "/~antonio/project/it/men") {
    $this->redirect("/~antonio/project/it/uomme");
}
```

Rinse and repeat per combination of language/word

Comment: How many languages are you supporting? and how is the language selection done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do this in htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/~antonio/project/it/donna/shoes/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^it/donna/shoes/(.*)$ /~antonio/project/it/donna/calzature/$1 [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not work without setting up a proper Virtual Host (so that instead of local urls like `http://localhost/~antonio/project/it/women` you have nice urls like `http://project1.dev`). But I would do that anyway, since it makes your dev environment nicer! ([Here's a place to start](http://drupal.org/node/238805)).

Anyway, I would try this: just leave the `.htaccess` file set [like you normally would for "path" style urls](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#hiding-x-23x), and then just parse a `$_GET['lang']` parameter using the UrlManager? So you would have a urlManager setup like this in your config.php:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
  'urlFormat'=>'path', // use path style parameters
  'showScriptName'=>false, // get rid of index.php
  'rules'=>array(
    // this parses out the first chunk of url into the "lang" GET parameter
    '<lang:[\w\-]+>/<controller:[\w\-]+>/<action:[\w\-]+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
  )
)
```

This way a url like this `http://project1.dev/it/controller/action` will redirect to the "action" action in your Controller like normal (controller/action), but in your action `$_GET['lang']` will now have the value of "it".

I hope that helps, it's kind of a shot in the dark. I'm not sure how you are actually triggering the different languages, so a $_GET parameter might not be helpful after all.